# How do I reply to "I'm Sorry?"

Tags: meaning

I've seen the usage of "I'm sorry", but now I saw those with "?" mark. Been googling it for a while and one of the results said it's the same as "Excuse me?", asking for confirmation. So how do I reply to that?

Comment: To make one repeat, clarify, or to say that you didn't understand what the other said, the words/word groups used in the past were excuse me, pardon?, beg your pardon..., your mean to say?... etc.  I'm sorry is not very old.  Somehow, I feel 'why should one be sorry for seeking clarification from the other?'  May be I am a little blunt towards the abuse of the words sorry and thank you...

Comment: You would reply to "I'm sorry?" the same way you would reply to "Excuse me?"

Comment: I take the expression to mean *Forgive me, could you repeat yourself?* Still, I'd rephrase before repeating myself.

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer on the basis of the spoken word so cannot give references as is usually done on this site.

The pseudo-question “I’m sorry?” is used in the sense of *“I heard what you said but do you really mean it?”*, “*What? Do you expect me to believe that?”*, “*You’ve interrupted me. What do you want?*”, or “*I don’t agree with you. Explain yourself*”.

It is often often delivered slightly disdainfully, as if the speaker can hardly believe there is any possible explanation for the statement or interruption.

The best reply is to act neutrally and politely and to answer on the basis of one of the above understandings.

Edit: I am grateful for comments that add the idea that *Excuse me?* may be simply a request to repeat what was not heard.

Comment: I agree with everything in the answer, my experience is tone of voice & inflection also influences the meaning of  the pseudo-question “I’m sorry?”. I've experienced it to also mean: "I misheard you, could please repeat what you said" or "I didn't understand what you said"

Comment: @Fred it can also mean "I can tell that you said something but I didn't hear what it was". That meaning is particularly common in noisy environments.

Comment: While this is certainly a commonly used meaning, it can also still be used as a way to indicate that they didn't understand what was being said. It's very contextual.

Answer (score -3):

It's a question as if to ask if they will accept the apology. Using the form of telling a child to do or state "I apologize" is the action of or the verb form as you are committing the act of apologizing. Your original phrase "I'm sorry?" is a statement of offering a possession or feeling. Kinda like giving your gratitude, would make it a noun as it's not physical or material, it's still a thing. Just like anything else, you can't force someone to accept or receive something. At least, it isn't good manners. Especially, if you've already wronged them in someway for which is the ultimate reason of offering your apology in hopes that they'll accept it by following it up with "forgiving" that individual most commonly with one of two phrases. Either "I accept" or I've always preferred, "Your forgiven".

Comment: I guess I did overlook the fact that it is sometimes used as a short version of asking someone to repeat themselves when they weren't heard clearly or potentially asked to clarify further as to what was meant or intended to have meant by the statement in question. I was taught if someone wasn't clear enough or your not sure of something regarding the conversation, of course, apologize because it could have potentially been a mistake on your own party as to why you're in need of further detail. However, along with the apology, I almost always specify what I'm unclear on and need further detail.